# Backtracking to find source of birth date?

Tags: birth-records, wales, sources

I have been tracing an ancestor of mine Catherine Cowin (nee Jones).

I have been getting complacent and foolishly forgot to put in sources I had found for her DOB and the place of birth when I found them online, and now I can't think where I got them from. I know that I didn't pluck them out of thin air but it certainly feels like I did.

I have put her date of birth down as 24th of December 1878 for some reason, even though the 1911 census record I have placed her year of birth to be 1882. I have also placed her place of birth in Carmarthenshire. I have also entered that she lived on St Oswald Street, but can't remember where I got that from.

Can anyone help me backtrack and find the sources of this information? I'm feeling very stuck now.

Comment: If you use Ancestry.com could you have copied them from somebody else's tree?  In any event where you store your tree/sources may be useful information to include in your question.

Comment: @PolyGeo I use family search mainly and my tree is on there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect it was the [1939 Register](https://search.findmypast.com/search-world-records/1939-register), as that shows a [Catherine Cowin](https://search.findmypast.com/record/locked?id=tnnco3qcnsmpqjrnav5hrrow3g4ufi6onj6qpncptplayyl3ktca%3D%3D%3D%3D&enc=true) with birth date 24 Dec 1878 living in Liverpool C.B.

Keep in mind that birth dates on the 1939 Register were recorded as given by the household head, and errors were not uncommon. Frequently I find the year slightly off. For more information on birth date errors see [How accurate are birth dates on the 1939 Register?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/11796/how-accurate-are-birth-dates-on-the-1939-register)

Comment: Mistakes can happen. I must have been very tired when I wrote in those dates too because its a different Catherine Cowin!